# Wait until an event is fired in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am writing a function in my server to return data from client A to client B at the time client B is sending request. When function is called, my server send request to client A and then client A send data back to server. The problem is how to make this function wait until server received data from client A.

I already use `setTimeout` and it worked for me but it not flexible

```
//the code for receiving data from client A is written in another file
socketA.emit('getData', JSON.stringify(json));
//I want my function will stopping here
socketB.emit('sendData', somedata);
```

This is my code for receiving data from client

```
socket.on('getData', (data) =>{
   storage_data = data;
});
```

I expect there is a way to stop my function without using `setTimeout` or if I make something wrong, please tell me.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you emit data to client B on the receive event itself while writing data to the file?

Comment: Thank for your reply, because it have another client connected to server and I want receive event is just receive, not send to another. If there is noway for my problem, I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: Or you can use nodejs event emitter to create an event and then emit when client A send data. and on that custom event you can send data back to client B.

Comment: Don't wait, just do your task, when I'm done I callback to you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Promise is a definitely way (I not sure, but just give it a try).This
[Asynchronous in NodeJS](https://medium.com/dev-bits/writing-neat-asynchronous-node-js-code-with-promises-32ed3a4fd098) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with async/await syntax

```
socket.on('getData', async (data) =>{
   storage_data = await data;
});
```

For reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await